# Any method faster than count(*) for counting mysql rows

Tags: mysqli, count, query-performance

We exactly know that count(*) is faster than mysql_num_rows, but is it enough for to be more faster?

- firma table has 575.000 rows
- onay, bireysel, bastarih, uyeliktur has INDEX on firma table

My simple query is...

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT('x') as num  FROM    firma   where 1 and firma.onay=1 and firma.bireysel=0 ";
$res = mysqli_query($i_link,$sql);
$row= mysqli_fetch_row($res);
echo    $db_count =  $row['0'];
```

This query is working after nearly 5 or 6 seconds

Test link: http://celikhane.com/firmalar/

How to fasten this query to run under 1 second.

> NOTE: if i changed query
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT('x') as num FROM firma where firma.onay=1
> ```
>
> it is 0,6 seconds and really faster but i must use other conditions.

Comment: in SQL Server, it's faster to do Count('x') instead of count(*).  Maybe the same for mySql?

Comment: @JohnieKarr I think you can write it as answer.

Comment: i changed it to count(id) but still same seconds near 5-6, so it doesnt work unfurtunately.

Comment: @Bagova, try count('x').  The point is that you don't do a count on a column.  I can't remember the technical reason why this is faster, but count(id) and count(*) should have the same performance.  Just try, count('ANY CHARACTER HERE, INSIDE SINGLE QUOTES')

Comment: Also, I meant the caps to be emphasis, not yelling...sorry

Comment: Not sure if it will help your problem any, but couldn't you remove the first condition in your where clause?  So, select....from firma where firma.onay = 1 and ...

Comment: sorry, Nothing change when i delete 1 after where..

Comment: why you did order by?where you only need count

Comment: Ah you found it.So try without order by may be its taking time for that.BTW your question title does not match with your question.So people may answer wrong.

Comment: i delete order by but still it is nearly 5 seconds , nothing changed.. if i used two conditions it is slow, but if i use one condition it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try `count('x')` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: You can check in test page, there ise no big change, it is still performing nearly 5 seconds.